OrderedDict with fully custom key order
I know that keys have no order in a dict (even, if, they keep the insertion order in the recent implementations, as I saw this in CPython core developer Hettinger's video, but this is out of topic).
Is there a data structure in Python that behaves like a dict, but for which the key order can be customized, and the order is guaranteed to be preserved? (for example after a pickle dump + load, etc.)
Obviously, collections.OrderedDict seems a good candidate, but finally not, because we cannot fully customize the order of the keys, but only move to beginning or end: move_to_end.

Why do you need such data structure?

the builtin dict preserves order for quite a while now.

@KarolyHorvath Yes, but I also need to be able to customise the order.

You can use the ordered dict and sort it with a list that keeps track of the order

@Basj: Create a new one (or clear it) and add to it with the new order

@KarolyHorvath This is unconvenient, better would be an OrderedDict-like object that offers the possibility to customize the order, without recreating one each time.

the builtin dict preserves order for quite a while now. @KarolyHorvath: it is the case in the current implementation, but is this considered as a real specification of a dict that will never change? I doubt so.

Once you are done with mutations, can you (re)set the order via my_dict = dict(sorted((p for p in my_dict.items()), key=<my_customer sorter>)) ?

@Basj yes, insertion order preservation has been declared as part of the spec: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html

@JonSG You're right: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict Changed in version 3.7: Dictionary order is guaranteed to be insertion order. This behavior was an implementation detail of CPython from 3.6.

you could create own class with own __getitem__, __setitem__, __iter__, .keys(),.items(), etc

here is source code for collections.OrderedDict and you could use it to create own dictionary.

You really should include a concrete example of the use cases you want to satisfy. Think how unit tests define required functionality.

As of Python 3.6, the Dictionary data structure was replaced to hold the Insert Order.
If you want to use Built-in structures, you can use priorityqueue this way you can determine the sequence according to your own.

import math
from queue import PriorityQueue

class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    
    @staticmethod
    def of(x, y):
        return Point(x, y)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Point: x:{self.x} y:{self.y}"
    
    def get_distance(self, other):
        return math.sqrt((self.x - other.x) ** 2 + (self.y - other.y) ** 2)

# Example usage
my_point = Point.of(9, 2)
point_array = [Point(1, 5), Point(5, 65), Point(9, 2)]

queue = PriorityQueue()
for point in point_array:
    queue.put((point.get_distance(my_point), point))

while not queue.empty():
    distance, point = queue.get()
    print(point)

In this example I created a PriorityQueue so as to sort them according to their respondent distance to my_point.

What does this have to do with dictionaries?

Since you can not set custom order of dicrionaries, priorityQueues came for rescue.

So, this doesn't answer the question then.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
